# Node: Callback was already called

Tags: node.js, callback

I know that here are few duplicate questions about this. However, I don't know how to solve this problem. My code is this:

```
/**
 * DEFINE
 * @connection_kill
 */
apiRoutes.post('/balancer_connection_drop', function(req, res) {
    /* BALANCER - connection kill */
    async.auto({
        decrypt_kill: function(callback, drop, user, stream) {
            /* DROP - decrypt */
            try {
                /* DEFINE - drop */
                var drop = JSON.parse(decrypt(Object.keys(req.body)[0], encryption));

                /* DROP - user & stream */
                callback(null, drop['drop'], drop['user'], drop['stream']);
            } catch(s) {
                /* CLOSE - connection */
                res.end();
            }
        },
        remove_connection: ['decrypt_kill', function(results, callback) {
            /* DROP - balancer || user & stream */
            if ((results[Object.keys(results)[0]])[0] !== 'null') {
                /* DROP - balancer users */
                if (results[Object.keys(results)[0]][0] == 'balancer') {
                    console.log('callback users...');
                    /* DROP - balancer users */
                    pool.query('UPDATE live SET remove=?',[1], function(err, results) {
                        /* DROP - failed */
                        if (err) return callback('Could NOT Drop Users From Live Table!');
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log('callback user...');
                    /* DROP - balancer user */
                    pool.query('UPDATE live SET remove=? WHERE user=? AND stream=?',[1, results[Object.keys(results)[0]][1], results[Object.keys(results)[0]][2]], function(err, results) {
                        /* DROP - failed */
                        if (err) return callback('Could NOT Drop Users From Live Table!');
                    })
                }
            } else {
                console.log('failed to kill data empty...');
                return callback('Balancer Connection Kill Data Empty!');
            }
            console.log('callback...');
            callback();
        }]
    }, function(err, results) {
        /* CHECK - error */
        if (err) return res.send(encrypt(JSON.stringify({'status': 'false'}), encryption));
        /* DROP - success */
        res.send(encrypt(JSON.stringify({'status': 'true'}), encryption));
        /* END - connection */
        res.end();
    })
})
```

Now when I call this api C get this error from node:

> Callback was already called

So I put in code console.log to see what is twice called and I get this from console.log before it throws error that is twice called:

```
callback user...
callback...
```

So I see that I made mistake that I call it twice but I don't know how to rewrite above code to work as it should be so when callback user... is called. I need to go to

```
function(err, results) {
```

function  and in that function return json to my server api, but I don't know how to rewrite it. I try using this code above to move callback outside functions but then callback is never called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You make a callback after you handle err in pool.query
- The problem is that pool.query is an async task and node jumps over
  that async task after pushing it to libuv
- it reaches the last callback() before pool.query callback function;
- the last callback is called after your code reaches
  pool.query callback function

```
    apiRoutes.post('/balancer_connection_drop', function(req, res) {

    /* BALANCER - connection kill */
    async.auto({
        decrypt_kill: function(callback, drop, user, stream) {
            /* DROP - decrypt */
            try {
                /* DEFINE - drop */
                var drop = JSON.parse(decrypt(Object.keys(req.body)[0], encryption));

                /* DROP - user & stream */
                callback(null, drop['drop'], drop['user'], drop['stream']);
            } catch(s) {
                /* CLOSE - connection */
                res.end();
            }
        },
        remove_connection: ['decrypt_kill', function(results, callback) {
            /* DROP - balancer || user & stream */
            if ((results[Object.keys(results)[0]])[0] !== 'null') {
                /* DROP - balancer users */
                if (results[Object.keys(results)[0]][0] == 'balancer') {
                    console.log('callback users...');
                    /* DROP - balancer users */
                    pool.query('UPDATE live SET remove=?',[1], function(err, results) {
                        /* DROP - failed */
                        if (err){ return callback('Could NOT Drop Users From Live Table!');}
 
                      return callback();
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log('callback user...');
                    /* DROP - balancer user */
                    pool.query('UPDATE live SET remove=? WHERE user=? AND stream=?',[1, results[Object.keys(results)[0]][1], results[Object.keys(results)[0]][2]], function(err, results) {
                        /* DROP - failed */
                        if (err){ return callback('Could NOT Drop Users From Live Table!');}

                           return callback();
                    })
                }
            } else {
                console.log('failed to kill data empty...');
                return callback('Balancer Connection Kill Data Empty!');
            }
            
        }]
    }, function(err, results) {
        /* CHECK - error */
        if (err) return res.send(encrypt(JSON.stringify({'status': 'false'}), encryption));
        /* DROP - success */
        res.send(encrypt(JSON.stringify({'status': 'true'}), encryption));
        /* END - connection */
        res.end();
    })
})
```

Comment: good answer. try using bullet points if you're concerned your English grammar is not 100%

Answer (score 0):

Put a `return` in front of the `pool.query` calls. Your code execution is falling through the `if statement` to,

```
...
console.log('callback...');
callback();
```

FYI,

You already have an `if-else` catching all paths so why do you have this?

```
...
console.log('callback...');
callback();
```

Comment: i have this callback() at end if no callback in if with error is called that callback() call next function without error,..in short terms when we don't have error callback in if statements callback() to indicate that function successfully finished without error...

Answer (score 0):

```
    remove_connection: ['decrypt_kill', function(results, callback) {
        /* DROP - balancer || user & stream */
        if ((results[Object.keys(results)[0]])[0] !== 'null') {
            /* DROP - balancer users */
            if (results[Object.keys(results)[0]][0] == 'balancer') {
                console.log('callback users...');
                /* DROP - balancer users */
                pool.query('UPDATE live SET remove=?',[1], function(err, results) {
                    /* DROP - failed */
                    if (err) return callback('Could NOT Drop Users From Live Table!');
                })
            } else {
                console.log('callback user...');
                /* DROP - balancer user */
                pool.query('UPDATE live SET remove=? WHERE user=? AND stream=?',[1, results[Object.keys(results)[0]][1], results[Object.keys(results)[0]][2]], function(err, results) {
                    /* DROP - failed */
                    if (err) return callback('Could NOT Drop Users From Live Table!');
                })
            }
        } else {
            console.log('failed to kill data empty...');
            return callback('Balancer Connection Kill Data Empty!');
        }
        console.log('callback...');
        callback();
    }]
```

Because `pool.query` is an asynchronous operation, the `callback()`after `console.log('callback...');` will be called before they complete. If they fail, they will call it again.

I'd remove the last `callback()`call and call it after each async call runs, like this:

```
    remove_connection: ['decrypt_kill', function(results, callback) {
        /* DROP - balancer || user & stream */
        if ((results[Object.keys(results)[0]])[0] !== 'null') {
            /* DROP - balancer users */
            if (results[Object.keys(results)[0]][0] == 'balancer') {
                console.log('callback users...');
                /* DROP - balancer users */
                pool.query('UPDATE live SET remove=?',[1], function(err, results) {
                    /* DROP - failed */
                    if (err) return callback('Could NOT Drop Users From Live Table!');
                    callback();
                })
            } else {
                console.log('callback user...');
                /* DROP - balancer user */
                pool.query('UPDATE live SET remove=? WHERE user=? AND stream=?',[1, results[Object.keys(results)[0]][1], results[Object.keys(results)[0]][2]], function(err, results) {
                    /* DROP - failed */
                    if (err) return callback('Could NOT Drop Users From Live Table!');
                    callback();
                })
            }
        } else {
            console.log('failed to kill data empty...');
            return callback('Balancer Connection Kill Data Empty!');
        }
    }]
```

Comment: I added as you suggested but i get from console.log now 
callback user... and that is correct but it does not return api to my server now...i will investigate why..

Comment: I didn't look at the business logic of your code, but I assume you need to pass the values returned by `pool.query`. So you'll probably want to call `callback(null, results)` after pool.query resolves and use those results at the end.